# Let a line snap to the center of a point

Tags: actionscript-3, snapping

I'm making a *touchscreen* connect-the-dots game for my internship in AS3, here's a quick epitome of my game flow:

1. The user selects a level.
2. The image/coordinates from that level loads and the image gets added to the stage.
3. When the coordinates of the dots are loaded (XML), the dots get MovieClips (`circlePoint`) attached to them. All of these MovieClips have a unique value (`circlePoint.id`) and a `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER` listener which fires `clickPoint()`. The MovieClips get pushed in my `pointContainer`.
4. A straight line follows my mouse which starts at the first dot.
5. If my `gameCounter` variable is the same as the MovieClip's `id`, the line will snap to the dot and a new line will start following my mouse. Of course this new line starts at the last dot that has been touched.

All of this is working like a charm, but I'm facing one problem; if my mouse collides with the MovieClip, the line snaps at the current mouse position. That position is the corner of my `circlePoint` and I want it to be the center. So I decided to let the new line start at the center of the current dot. But the previous line is still at the corner of the `circlePoint` and the new one starts in the center, it doesn't look very nice. I was thinking of decreasing the size of my dots but the dots will get too small to touch, since it's a touchscreen game. This is what I've written so far:

```
private function setStartPoint():void{
    mouseLines.push(new Sprite);
    stage.addChild(mouseLines[mouseLines.length-1]);
    holderX = pointContainer.getChildAt(0).x;
    holderY = pointContainer.getChildAt(0).y;
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setStartPoint);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseFollower);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickPoint);
}
```

The `setStartPoint()` function is triggered when all the MovieClips are added to the stage.

```
private function clickPoint(e:MouseEvent):void{
    if(gameCounter == e.target.id){
        holderX = e.target.x;
        holderY = e.target.y;
        mouseLines[mouseLines.length-1].graphics.lineTo(holderX, holderY);
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseFollower);

        gameCounter++;
        mouseLines.push(new Sprite);
        stage.addChild(mouseLines[mouseLines.length-1]);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseFollower);
    }
}
```

`clickPoint()` gets fired on `MOUSE_OVER` as stated above.

```
private function mouseFollower(e:MouseEvent):void{
    mouseLines[mouseLines.length-1].graphics.clear();
    mouseLines[mouseLines.length-1].graphics.lineStyle(5,0x0000FF);
    mouseLines[mouseLines.length-1].graphics.moveTo(holderX, holderY);
    mouseLines[mouseLines.length-1].graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    mouseLines[mouseLines.length-1].mouseEnabled = false;
}
```

The `mouseFollower()` function draws the line on `MOUSE_MOVE`. And `mouseEnabled` is, of course, set to false so it's not clickable.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like what you are trying to do here is comparable to Drawing a freeform in a graphics program(such as Photoshop). Therefore I think you are making things to complicated for yourself. You could just have the center of the circles be vectors and subsequently draw a line between them. Then you could easily say something like.

```
private function mouseFollower(e:MouseEvent):void{
  if(e.Hittest){
    DrawLine(lastVector,curVector);
  }
}
```

(this is pseudo code so.)

Comment: I see what you mean. A non-pseudo code example would be appreciated but I can try to figure it out myself.